# How to view (and make) a huge seamless picture made of smaller images?

Tags: image-editing, photo-stitching

I'd like to be able to view a gigantic picture (approx. 150'000 × 50'000 px) made of smaller images (4096 × 4096 px each). Are there any software or web applications for that?

---

also on topic:

There is a Very Large Image Viewer (VLIV) application on the internet.

Comment: You want something like Microsoft's http://zoom.it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hugein: http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tech/ It's free and works on Mac, Windows and Linux.

Comment: Unfortunately I have source images that aren't recognized as coherent by this application and it doesn't stitch them together automatically.

Comment: @user1306322: Not "coherent"? As in, format not recognised? What format images are they? Are you sure those images aren't corrupted in any way?

Comment: Images are fine. Program says it can't find any common points to stick together by, that's all. So basically it's of no use to me if it can't do even that, and I'm looking for something to view them with after stitching together.

Comment: The problem is not in making one big picture out of many smaller ones, but in viewing that monster of an image in some way that won't hang the computer or lag terribly.

Comment: @user1306322: Ah. Well, considering the amount of processing power but especially RAM that will be required, and the amount of scrolling/panning you'll probably need to do, I don't see what the advantage is. Why do you want to view the stitched image anway - to confirm that the joins are good?

Comment: @Karan Actually, I don't. I figured out those "map" API services provide me exactly what I want, but they require even smaller tiles than I have, so I guess I need to cut my images now :P